# How to trim string and remove characters from string in bash?

Tags: bash

I have this:

```
$ git show -s --format=%ci HEAD
2017-08-21 20:35:28 +0200
```

How can trim the string at the first space and then remove the dashes, so that I end up with an environment variable with value `20170821`?

I tried this, but it didn't work...:

```
MYDATE=`git show -s --format=%ci HEAD`
MYDATE=${MYDATE%" "} # trim at the first space
MYDATE=${MYDATE//-}. # remove dashes
```

Comment: That's a regular shell variable, not an environment variable. A shell variable only becomes an environment variable if you `export` it (which you shouldn't do unnecessarily), or if there already existed an environment variable by the same name in your program's environment.

Comment: BTW, POSIX-specified convention indicates that all-caps variable names are used for variables with meaning to the shell and operating system; see http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html, fourth paragraph, which guarantees that (only) lower-case variable names are safe for use without modifying shell behavior. (This applies to regular shell variables because of their behavior of overwriting like-named environment variables if such exist).

Comment: (well -- variable names *containing lower-case characters*, rather; `MyVar` is safe, as is `myvar`, whereas `MYVAR` is not).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The replacement `${MYDATE%" "}` will remove a single space from the end of the string.  To match space followed my more text, we need to add a `*`, and to remove the longest matching substring, we need `%%` rather than `%`.  We don't need to quote the space in the substitution, so the simplest equivalent is `${MYDATE%% *}`.

Demo:

```
$ MYDATE='2017-08-21 20:35:28 +0200'
$ echo ${MYDATE%% *}
2017-08-21
```

From a cursory reading of the `git show` documentation, it appears that [you can get the output in the format you want](/a/7853670), without having to do any extra work subsequently:

```
git show -s --format=%cd --date=short HEAD

# Or, using a standard `strftime` format string:
git show -s --format=%cd --date=format:%F HEAD
```

These both give an ISO-8601 format date; if you want it without the `-` separators, then you'll need a format string of `%Y%m%d`:

```
git show -s --format=%cd --date=format:%Y%m%d HEAD
```

Comment: Thanks, this is great. I ended up using this: `git show -s --format=%cd --date=format:'%Y%m%d'` which gives me `20170821`.

Comment: Thanks, @BenjaminW.  I knew what I meant, but I didn't find the right words!

Answer (score 2):

To manipulate the string so it matches your desired output, use:

```
${MYDATE/ */}
```

It'll extract the substring before first space it finds.

Edit: Just to elaborate a little bit more, this is [substring replacement](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html), we're just using a short expression that matches everything after the first space and replacing it with nothing. Also, I just noticed the 'remove dashes' portion of the question, you can use the following statement:

```
tr -d '-' <<< ${MYDATE/ */}
```

Will result in`20170821`

Answer (score 0):

Simple way to do- If you don't want to focus much on git utility and consider using bash commands to manipulate the string output - use **cut**

```
MYDATE=`git show -s --format=%ci HEAD | cut -d' ' -f1`
```

Comment: None of the other answers are using `git`-specific commands -- parameter expansion (as in `${varname##" "*}`) is bash-native syntax, and much more efficient than forking off a pipeline to run external commands (like `cut`) that aren't actually part of the shell. See http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe, and [BashFAQ #100](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/100). (And on the subject of using modern syntax -- `$()` is fully POSIX-compliant, and strongly preferred over backticks -- being easier to nest, and avoiding syntax with side effects on how enclosed content is parsed).

Comment: Thanks Charles for info. Good information on parameter expansion. By the way cut is part of GNU coreutils and almost all linux based OS has this utility. I find it quiet handy to manually operate on strings, as it's easy to do. But I agree here on using bash-native syntax that's always faster to do than fork a new pipe.

Comment: coreutils is, as you imply, specific to Linux -- other operating systems aren't guaranteed to have coreutils-provided tools. That said, `cut` specifically is also [POSIX-specified](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/cut.html), which provides a stronger guarantee of cross-platform availability. That said, my point was *specifically* that cut wasn't a bash built-in, such that bash needs to perform an `execv`-family syscall to run it, linking and loading a separate executable after forking a process to run it in: the distinction was about performance, not availability.